# Background mode not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins

I have error when try to use [background mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git) It says: Cannot read property 'enable' of 'undefined'.

```js
window.plugin.backgroundMode.enable(); 

cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() 
{
  setTimeout(function () 
             {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule([{
      id: 1,
      title: "Some Title",
      text: "Some text!"
    },{
      id: 2,
      title: "Some Title",
      text: "Some text!"
    },{
      id: 3,
      title: 'Some Title',
      text: 'Some text!'
    }]);
  }, 5000);
}
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

Comment: Okay, what have you done?

Comment: **Please [edit] the question and add it.**

Comment: sry i dont know how to use this site , am new

Comment: I understand. Please click on [edit], add your code. Select it. Press Ctrl + K. And then save. `:)`

Comment: Yes yes... People will answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the right method.  This is the right call:

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

Also make sure you have added the plugin to config.xml and are only calling methods on the plugin after the deviceready event has fired.

Comment: Have you added the plugin from the command line in your project directory?